# Jquery GoogleMaps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Can anyone say good Jquery plugin to insert markers to map by click and Json. And also how to organise poup up when inserting point?

Tnx

Solution found:
**http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/examples.php**

Comment: I like this plugin http://googlemaps.mayzes.org/ but how to organise adding new marker onClick?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at gMap.

http://gmap.nurtext.de/documentation.html

I think it could be customized easily to add markers with a click :)

Comment: Sorry, but I am newbie about google maps and have no time to learn API

Comment: That's not an API, it's a jQuery plugin.